# Is it possible to do SQL queries and upload files to directories to other websites?

Tags: php, sql

Me and my friend are partnering our websites, and his is an image sharing website..

So we decided to implement a image sharing feature on my site. Is this possible to do?

Comment: We need more information to help you.

Comment: Explain what kind of image sharing you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you really have the cooperation of the other web site and assuming that the other web site is running something other than straight HTML pages then you can work with the programmer at the other web site to provide an API that will allow you to perform certain pre-programmed functions against his web site.

One common way to do this is to use the existing HTML mechanism, designing a RESTful API to the other site, and then issuing HTML PUT, GET, POST, and DELETE commands to the other website.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not. Otherwise anyone could deface any website.
You can only write to other websites if you have FTP/SCP/... access or there's an API giving you access to it.

Comment: Yes, I have FTP access.. why would I be talking about this if I didn't?

Answer (score 1):

What you would probably have to do is set up a web page, most likely password secured where you could post the file to his site for processing.  One way of doing this is to submit an XML document with your authentication credentials and the image data and other meta information about the image to a PHP/ASP.Net/whatever page that is on your friends server that knows what to do with the image.